# How to make a bootable Ubuntu USB on MAC running 10.7.5?

Tags: usb, mac

I'm using a 2008 MacBook and the newest version of OS X it can run (10.7.5). The program to create the bootable USB on the Ubuntu website doesn't work.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dd` command from the Terminal:

```
dd if=path_to_your_image.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

Replace `/dev/sdX` by your USB stick's. You can find the `/dev/sdX` device path matching your USB with this command: `diskutil list`

`dd` needs a few seconds or minutes to write your ISO (depending on its size), just wait until your command prompt comes back and you'll have a bootable USB.

Answer (score 1):

[Download UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) for Mac OS X and create the bootable USB with the Ubuntu ISO-file.

UNetbootin is self-explainable, version-independent and works pretty fine on all systems.

Comment: You can also use [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) which offers similar features.